# Admob interstitial ad in LibGDX shows banner?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob, interstitial

I am trying to display an interstitial in LibGDX after the title screen. I implemented the official github code: https://github.com/TheInvader360/tutorial-libgdx-google-ads/commit/0a5ea376d4eb92b8e87c13a03245adb40b53e811

The code is working fine but I think I'm missing something because whenever I call the showOrLoadInterstital() function, it displays a banner. I want to display a full screen ad instead.

In the code I see an adView being initialized with settings for a banner, but the mentioned function showOrLoadInterstital() uses the InterstitialAd, which is correct. As a beginning game developer (but not beginning developer in general), I am not getting the hang of this, especially those two different ad types together.

Could someone tell me what I am missing here? Should showOrLoadInterstital() just not show a full ad when I call it in my Game class?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you create a full screen ad (interstitial instead of banner) in AdMob and are you using the correct ID for that ad?

Comment: Hi islander_zero. Yes, I created both types in AdMob and used the correct IDs in the code. As far as I know, it's not strange it shows the banner, since it initializes the AdView upon start. I tried not adding it to the layout and it doesn't show up. I know little about the InterstitialAd and can't find much info. Doesn't it need its own View? (As far as I can see there is no View created for it). Also, can I call the function before or after the OrthographicCamera is set? It would be great if I could be put on the right track.